# How to store the Messages In JMS Queue Using Wso2esb and Activemq

Tags: wso2, activemq-classic, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am using wso2esb4.7.0 and ActiveMQ5.8.0 i wish to store the messages in Queue 
for this i try with this code but its not working
i created store which will helpful for storing the messages,my conumeing process has done in JAVA code so i need not worry about the Consuming
if i do it my message will appear in acivemq UI
my config is like this

```
<messageStore name="JMSQueue" class="org.wso2.carbon.message.store.persistence.jms.JMSMessageStore" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
   <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://localhost:61616</parameter>
   <parameter name="store.jms.destination">faisal5_Queue</parameter>
   <parameter name="store.jms.JMSSpecVersion">1.1</parameter>
   <parameter name="store.jms.cache.connection">false</parameter>
</messageStore>
```

and i am trying to pass the message through the proxy for that i write simple proxy service for that

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="Jms"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <store messageStore="JMSQueue"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

in this case my queue is not creating in Activemq Why its happening
if i create message process then only my QUEUE is appearing in ActiveMQ UI 
will you write sample code for this my scenario is simple i wsih to store my client messages without failure they will consume after the storing process

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the below config to store messages in activemq.
Since you are not using a message processor, it is no need of making a message store. So you can simple store messages in the queue as follows.

```
<proxy name="JmsProxyTest"
      transports="https http"
      startOnLoad="true"
      trace="disable">
  <target endpoint="jmsEndpoint">
     <inSequence>
        <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
        <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
     </inSequence>
     <outSequence>
        <drop/>
     </outSequence>
  </target>
```

```
 <endpoint name="jmsEndpoint">
  <address uri="jms:/faisal5_Queue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://127.0.0.1:61616&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue"/>
```

Also you better check you have configured activemq with esb correctly.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your proxy and message store are okay, I tested those.
I think you have not correctly Configure the ESB with ActiveMQ.

Follow this [link](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB470/Configure+with+ActiveMQ) and place the jars as mentioned and edit the Axis2.xml. Then try with your code. It should work